# jQuery Get -- mixing returned data with html

Tags: jquery, get

Just wondering if this is possible,

```
content:function(callback) {
    $.get('url', { data to pass to url }, 
    function(data) { 
        var text = callback(data);
        return "<div>" + text + "</div>";
    });
});
```

I am speaking specifically of line 5

```
return "<div>" + text + "</div>";
```

I tried doing this with a tooltip, the callback data is showing, but it is not getting wrapped into the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the strings and then call the callback, using `return` statement in the `$.get()` callback function practically doesn't do anything.

```
content: function(callback) {
    $.get('url', { data to pass to url }, 
    function(data) { 
        var content = "<div>" + data + "</div>";
        callback(content);
    });
},
```

Comment: @Anzeo I don't think so, since it's an async request, callback should be called for generating the tooltip's content.

Comment: Well I can't tell that for sure as I do not know the internals of the callback, but with the code there currently is, I would assume it would work as I described. Maybe the OP should provide some more details.

Comment: @Anzeo No, it shouldn't work, using `return` in the `$.get()` callback practically doesn't do anything. That's why there is another callback there.

Comment: This solution worked for me, thanks.  I only posted the above code because everything else appeared to be working fine.  It was a hang up on line 5 above, and after implementing BlackSheep suggestion I am back on track!